# create a UIImage or UIImageView with hexagonal corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Is it possible create an UIImage or an UIImageView with hexagonal corners? Because I want take an UIImage and show it inside an UIImageView but inside and hexagon. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723533/how-to-draw-hexagon-using-cgmutablepathref-in-ios

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities

Comment: yes, everything is possible.

Comment: @holex, of course but how?

Comment: you can create a subset of the `UIImageView`, and you can override the `–drawRect:` method, e.g. masking the actual content with a regular hexagon, which hexagon mask you could create using _CoreGraphics.framework_. piece of cake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while I found a simple implementation. I created an hexagonal view:

HexagonView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HexagonView : UIView
@end
```

HexagonView.m

```
#import "HexagonView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation HexagonView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat hPadding = width * 1 / 8 / 2;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width/2, 0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - hPadding, height / 4)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - hPadding, height * 3 / 4)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width / 2, height)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(hPadding, height * 3 / 4)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(hPadding, height / 4)];
    [path closePath];
    [path closePath];
    [path fill];
    [path stroke];

    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

}

@end
```

Then I add as subview my ImageView on HexagonView:

```
[hexagonView addSubview:scaledImageView];
```

And the result is this:
[image]

Comment: do you have any idea how to make its all 6 corner round

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442203/uibezierpath-triangle-with-rounded-edges (ok it's for a triangle, but you can apply the same way for an hexagon)

Comment: may i add its border?